# Select part of Json array based on a value from another column in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table where I store country information in a column and json data in another column.

I'd like to select only part of the json data, basically I'd like to find the country value inside the Json, and return the animals values from key "animals" that are the closest (and on the left side) to the country found in the json.

This is the table "myanimals":

| Country | Metadata |
| --- | --- |
| US | { "a": 1, "b": 2, "animals": ["dog","cat","mouse"], "region": {"country": "china"}, "animals": ["horse","bear","eagle"], "region": { "country": "us" } } |
| India | { "a": 20, "b": 40, "animals": ["fish","cat","rat","hamster"], "region": {"country": "india"}, "animals": ["dog","rabbit","fox","fish"], "region": { "country": "poland" } } |

Metadata is in json and NOT jsonb.

Using Postgres, I wanted to query so I'd end up with a new column, something like "animals_in_country", where the only information shown would be the values from key
"animals" which are the closest (and located on the left) to the matched country, as it follows:

| Country | Metadata | animals_in_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | { "a": 1, "b": 2, "animals": ["dog","cat","mouse"], "region": {"country": "china"}, "animals": ["horse","bear","eagle"], "region": { "country": "us" } } | ["horse","bear","eagle"] |
| India | { "a": 20, "b": 40, "animals": ["fish","cat","rat","hamster"], "region": {"country": "india"}, "animals": ["dog","rabbit","fox","fish"], "region": { "country": "poland" } } | ["fish","cat","rat","hamster"] |

Here's some pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve (please refer to the table shown above)

```
- Take the value in "Country", "US", and find the location of the same value in the JSON column
- location found, now search before this key 'country' for the key 'animals'
- Return whole array of values from 'animals'
- should be ["horse","bear","eagle"]
- shouldn't be ["dog","cat","mouse"] (as this one is part of "china" country in the JSON)
```

NOTE: Although this is dummy data, this is more or less the issue I am solving. And yes, the JSON is showing the same key more than once.

Comment: The values you are showing are invalid JSON to begin with  as you can't have a single JSON where the same key appears more than once. I also don't understand how you know to which region which array of animals belongs to (because order of elements inside a JSON has no meaning)

Comment: Hello, this is dummy data, but the same key is appearing more than once for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for the first animal in the array, this is your answer.

```
select  a.data->'animals'->0 as first_animal from myanimals a
where a.data->'region'->>'country'='us'
```

or without filter (for all countries)

```
select a.data->'region'->>'country' as country, 
a.data->'animals'->0 as first_animal from myanimals a
```

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your help! To be frank that is not what I wanted to achieve, though it is quite hard for me to explain it. In short, this is some sort of pseudo code of what I want to do (take the first row of my table above as an example).
1. Take the value in "Country", "US", and find the location of the same value in the JSON column
2. search before key 'country': "US" in JSON for the key 'animals'
3. Return whole array of values from 'animals'
4. should be ["horse","bear","eagle"]
5. shouldn't be ["dog","cat","mouse"] (as this one is part of "china" country in the JSON)

Comment: Get your point. I don't have any idea how to achieve that because there are duplicate keys in your JSON. Maybe you can put it "animal" inside into "region" at the same level with "country"